# How to split building query into multiple lines?

Tags: cakephp, orm, cakephp-3.0

I would like to build basic query ie:

```
            $query = $this->find('all')
            ->contain("Assets")
            ->order(['Transactions.created' => "DESC"])
            ->limit($count);
```

and then if (some condition is fulfilled) add

```
            ->where(['asset_id' => $asset_id])
```

can I do it? Or should I repeat the whole query in two versions (with and without the 'where' part)?

Comment: '''if(isset($asset_id)) {$query->where(['asset_id' => $asset_id])}'''??

Comment: @Salines I do not think this will work :/

Comment: It will work fine with your example.

Comment: @Salines sorry! You were right! 0_0 Thanks! And thanks @ndm!

Comment: @Salines if you write your comment as an answer I will mark it as correct one

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Short answer:

```
if(isset($asset_id)){
   $query->where(['asset_id' => $asset_id]);
}
```

Comment: @kicaj answer is also correct & working but this one is more straightforward

Answer (score 1):

Try something like this:

```
$query = $this->find('all')
    ->contain([
        'Assets' => function ($assets) use ($asset_id) {
            if (isset($asset_id)) {
                $assets->where([
                    'Assets.asset_id' => $asset_id
                ]);
            }

            return $assets;
        }
    ])->order(['Transactions.created' => "DESC"])
    ->limit($count);
```